Notation: Right-actions and wreath products
Let $G$ and $H$ be groups such that $H$ acts on a set $X$.
Suppose first that $H$ acts from the left, so $(h, x) \mapsto h.x$.
Then, we can form the permutational wreath product $G \wr_X H$, which is the semi-direct product $G^X \rtimes H$ whose operation is defined as
$$ ((g_x : x \in X), h) * ((g'_x : x \in X), h') = ((g_x g'_{h^{-1}.x} : x \in X), h h'). $$
In my context, I have a right-action of $H$ on $X$.
So, my question is what is the standard notation for it.
What I use now is the following.
Let us write the action $(h, x) \mapsto x.h$. Then, $H \wr_X G$ is the semi-direct $H \ltimes G^X$ with operation given by
$$ (h, (g_x : x \in X)) * (h', (g'_x : x \in X)) = (h h', (g_{x.h'} g'_x : x \in X)). $$
I really can't start using left-actions because that would imply using the postfix composition of functions in the second part of the paper I'm writing, which is too cumbersome for the type of computations I do. On the other hand, denoting wreath products by $H \wr_X G$ would confuse the readers, who might think that the base set is $H^X \times G$ instead of $G^X \times H$. Maybe, just being clear when I introduce the notation is enough to avoid such confusions.

It's actually the same thing. Note that if $H$ acts on $X$ on the right, then this defines a left action on $X$ by $h\cdot x = x.h^{-1}$. Using this definition, note that your construction amounts to exactly the same group, since the right action would give $x.h = h^{-1}\cdot x$, the usual construction.

@ArturoMagidin Yes, it is the same thing. The question is about what notation would be the best. If I use the second one, then I'd have to write "H \wr_X G$, which may be confusing since readers might think of $H^X \times G$ as the base set of the group.

My point is that you have the same underlying group (not just isomorphic groups, but the exact same group, with the same multiplication), so there is no need to use different notation. You can just say that you have a right action instead of a left action and use the same notation.

@ArturoMagidin Ohh I see, but it seems to me that there's a slight difference. In the first notation, I'd have to denote the elements of $G \wr_X H$ as $(g, h) \in G \wr_X H = G^X \rtimes H$, with $g = (g_x : x \in X) \in G^X$. In the second one, I'd write $(h, g) \in H \wr_X G = H \ltimes G^X$.

And I'm saying, again, that you should not do that. You should denote both as $G\wr_X H$, indicating that the action is on the right, because you get the exact same group.
